# Removing elements from a linked list with specific value

Tags: javascript, algorithm, while-loop, linked-list

I have this code written which works, but I have two questions that I can't explain to myself.

```
class ListNode {
    constructor(val) {
        this.val = val
        this.next = null
    }
}

const removeElements = (head, val) => {
    if (!head) return null // if no head
    let dummy = new ListNode('dummy') // dummy node
    dummy.next = head // to connect to the list
    head = dummy // point head to dummy

    while (dummy.next !== null) { // why is this not the same as while (!dummy.next)
        if (dummy.next.val === val) dummy.next = dummy.next.next
        else dummy = dummy.next
    }
    return head.next
}

const L1 = new ListNode(1)
L1.next = new ListNode(2)
L1.next.next = new ListNode(6)
L1.next.next.next = new ListNode(6) // this node confuses me
L1.next.next.next.next = new ListNode(4)
L1.next.next.next.next.next = new ListNode(5)
L1.next.next.next.next.next.next = new ListNode(6)

console.log(removeElements(L1, 6))
```

The first question is at nodes where the value is 6.  I understand that it will go to the `next.next` node, but I can't seem to figure out how the code works for two consecutive values of 6.  I would expect that at `L1.next.next.next` it would land on the 6 and not delete it; however, it does, and I can't seem to understand how.

The second question is about the while loop.  I was under the impression `while (dummy.next !== null)` and `while (!dummy.next)` were synonymous.  I have written code for several other algorithm problems using this exact logic, just not in a while loop, and it always behaved as predicted; however, in the while loop these two statements are not the same, can someone clarify why?

Comment: `null` is generally used as the value to determine end of list, so this is basically the reason for `while(dummy.next != null)` even if you do use `while(!dummy.next)` it won't make any difference

Comment: `how the consecutive values are removed ?`, in your if clause you're changing `dummy.next` only so on the next iteration `dummy.next.val` will point to next node which is `6`, but in your else clause you have `dummy = dummy.next` so on further iteration `dummy.next` is pointing to `next to next` node